# Can Ubuntu touch read NTFS formatted micro SD card?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ntfs

I get the following error:

> Failed to add storage device. Make sure device is formatted correctly.

I was under the impression that Ubuntu can read NTFS formatted discs. Is that correct? FAT has a 4 GB limit, which is problematic with large files.

Comment: Does it have `ntfs-3g` package installed? Is NTFS listed in `$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs`?

Comment: It is recommended to format your microSD to exFAT ( = extended FAT). exFAT supports files larger than 4 GB, especially if the SD has a newer standard like sdxc or uhs. exFAT is better supported by multimedia devices (cameras, phones, etc). I have a uhs microsd on my cardash camera and it works fine with exFAT (makes videos about 10 GB each).